# swift: segueing in tableview sections

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

**Problem:**

I have a tableView with 4 sections in it. In the first section the `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(String(indexPath.row), sender: self)` works fine, they segue according to their `indexPath.row` but once you scroll down to the second, third, and fourth sections and try tapping on them, the `indexPath.row` resets. I want to be able to use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(String(indexPath.row), sender: self)` all the way down the tableview without it being reset by the sections. Or in other words, how can I segue the cells per section.

**Example:**

Say in the first section there are 5 cells as well as the second section. In the first section the 5 cells segue to the correct view controllers in which the `indexPath.row` direct them. Once down to the second section, the `indexPath.row` resets and uses the same segues as above. The arrays are empty for privacy reasons.

**Code:**

```
struct Objects {
    var cellName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
    var detailObjects : [String]!
    var imageObjects : [String]!
}

var objectsArray = [Objects]()

objectsArray =
        [Objects(cellName: "example",
            sectionObjects: [],
            detailObjects: [],
            imageObjects: []),
        Objects(cellName: "example2",
            sectionObjects: [],
            detailObjects: [],
            imageObjects: []),
        Objects(cellName: "example3",
            sectionObjects: [],
            detailObjects: [],
            imageObjects: []),
        Objects(cellName: "example4",
            sectionObjects: [],
            detailObjects: [],
            imageObjects: [])]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(String(indexPath.row), sender: self)
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that just setting the `segueIdentifier` manually in an `if else`  statement for each section solved my problem:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        //art
        performSegueWithIdentifier((String(indexPath.row)), sender: nil)

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        //art galleries
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery1", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery2", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery3", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery4", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery5", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 5 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery6", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }

    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        //historic sites
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery7", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery8", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery9", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery10", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery11", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 5 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery12", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }

    } else if indexPath.section == 3 {
        //parks
        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery13", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery14", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 2 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery15", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 3 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery16", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 4 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery17", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        } else if indexPath.row == 5 {

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("gallery18", sender: self)
            tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        }
    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

}
```